# how to save a boolean numpy array to textfile in python?

Tags: python, numpy, save, boolean

The following saves floating values of a matrix into textfiles

`numpy.savetxt('bool',mat,fmt='%f',delimiter=',')`

How to save a boolean matrix ? what is the fmt for saving boolean matrix ?

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515373/how-to-dump-a-boolean-matrix-in-numpy

Comment: I want to output to be True or False or any representation from which I can read it using loadtxt() back into boolean numpy arrays. I was thinking if %r is more suitable than %s ?

Comment: If the main aim is to load the file back, why do you want to use a *text* file?  The binary representation used by `numpy.load()` and `numpy.save()` will be much more efficient.

Comment: Do you need `np.savetxt`/`np.loadtxt`? How about `np.save`/`np.load`?

Comment: Why not try '%d', In python, True/False are ints, so I don't see any reason why that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Thats correct, bools are integers, so you can always go between the two.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([True, True, False, False])
np.savetxt("test.txt", arr, fmt="%5i")
```

That gives a file with 1 1 0 0